# python asyncio invalid syntax ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

On OS X, my code works fine. Trying the exact code out on ubuntu, I get a syntax error:

```
ubuntu@home:server$ python3 server.py
  File "server.py", line 39
    async def hello(websocket, path):
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I used `pip3 install asyncio` to install asyncio

I also tried upgrading to python 3.5, but it causes a ton of library errors with other libraries, so far I can't get this working with python 3.5 on ubuntu although it works with python 3.5 on OS X.

Comment: async def is new to python3.5. https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.coroutine has an example of doing the same thing in 3.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have different versions of python on your OS X machine and your ubuntu machine.

[`async def` syntax was added in python 3.5](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/).

There's no hope of getting that syntax working on python 3.4.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your async / await functions with @asyncio.coroutine / yield from syntax and it should work

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def hello(websocket, path):
    yield from x
```